# Issue with connecting to database on Wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to get Wordpress up and running but I get the "Error establishing a database connection" page pop up.

Here is the setup and what I've done:

I have a server running Wordpress fine. I took a snapshot from the AWS volume that had the wp-config.php information from the running server and spawned a new server with a volume that is snapshotted. I've checked all my settings and it all looks fine.

On the SQL sever side (MYSQL), I added the new IP with all the correct username/passwords so the database server will allow it to connect. I also have put print statements while wordpress tries to load the database. The values returned are all correct. Based on some threads I read, I also deleted my wp-config file and re-copied it from the original server.

I also made sure the permissions are correct. Any other suggestions on what I could be missing?

Comment: either, wrong database name, username, host,password, table prefix or msql is down

Comment: No this is not the case. All these values are working on another server. Mysql server is up. double checked all parameters.

Comment: try connecting to database with simple php code using the same details

Comment: try connecting using the mysql client from cmd line using the same details. Do you get a connection refused, connection time out or username incorrect response?

Comment: Trying these, thanks

Comment: I just posted my answer. The steps mentioned above helped me in figuring out the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. The issue had nothing to do with Wordpress or the server, but with MYSQL. The database have Schema privileges and I hadn't set it for my new IP address. Adding the privileges fixed the issue.